# How do I enable profiling in node-mongodb-native?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I want to enable profiling on one of my MongoDB databases, via the node-mongodb-native driver.

However there doesn't seem to be a `Db.setProfilingLevel()` method (apart from on the Admin DB).

I've tried using `db.command({setProfilingLevel: 2})` but get `no such cmd: setProfilingLevel`.

Works fine through the mongo shell with `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see what you mean about the methods, but I think the issue with the db.command attempt is that you are trying to run a shell helper as a command rather than the command itself.  The actual command is this format:

```
// get current levels
db.runCommand({ profile : -1 })
// set the level to log slow ops
db.runCommand({ profile : 1 })
// set to log slow ops and change the threshold to 200ms
db.runCommand({ profile : 1, slowms : 200 })
//revert to defaults
db.runCommand({ profile : 0, slowms : 100 })
```

So, if you try passing the relevant value into db.command that should work.

Comment: and how can this be achieved in docker, so next time i'd start mongo profiling would be on?

Comment: I'd recommend a separate question if you need more help, but basically you would use a config file (https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/82591/6441) and specify it in there, assuming you can add/modify a config file and redeploy your container. Otherwise (or if the option is not available in the config) you would need to pass it into the command for running `mongod` in the container