# mongodb db.collection.find({}) does nothing past .limit(101)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

node-mongodb version 2.0.43 & MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5

centos vm

I have an (un-capped) collection of 1600 documents (not very big) and all of them have standard BSON _ids

if I do

```
db.collection('docs').find({}).limit(100).toArray(function(e,r){console.log('done');});
```

I wait about 1/2 a second for the result!

But, then if I do

```
db.collection('docs').find({}).toArray(function(e,r){console.log('done');})
```

I'm sitting here for 5-10 minutes and give up.

---

So then I set the limit to 200 (expecting the result to take x2 as long as limit 100, but it never comes)

Next I narrowed it down trying limits 150,101,110,105,103,102

and found that results stop after the 101 limit!

That seems totally void of usefulness and like there is a real problem to me.

If `limit(200)` took twice as long then I would say it's a performance issue in my query but it just hangs and 101 results is way way way unsatisfying!! **A poor assumption:** Not to mention my instant concern that at any point in time my app could hang If any query has above 100 items to look through)

each doc looks like so

```
{
"_id": "578eaa1ae642785679cd98b0",
"linkid": "12633170",
"advertisercid": "4612127",
"websitename": "Car Rental 8",
"destinationurl": "https://www.carrental8.com/en/",
"who": "8027061-12633170-1467924618000",
"href": "http://www.tkqlhce.com",
"src": "http://www.awltovhc.com",
"r1": 3,
"r2": 44,
"r3": 24,
"r4": 58
}
```

**Another assumption:** I don't think [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861909/how-do-i-enable-profiling-in-node-mongodb-native) will work on a query that does not finish?

Also what strikes me as very odd is that the query speed isn't really declining much up to 101 then BOOM nothing..

Why does the query hang forever and not just get slower?

*mongodb.log shows nothing wrong*

Tried `db.command({ profile : 1, slowms : 10 });` right before `find` but no profile seems to happen.

---

**yum update mongodb-org** *made no change although It did update:* mongodb-org-server, mongodb-org-mongos, mongodb-org-shell and mongodb-org-tools!

**Replicated the exact same collection onto a dedicated server**

It works there by not on the vm

the took a screen shot of the vm's memory before (blue) and after hanging (red) but I don't see a sizable change

[image]

added these two lines to /etc/security/limits.conf

```
root             soft    nofile          10000
root             hard    nofile          10000
```

also tried https://serverfault.com/questions/591812/how-to-set-ulimits-for-mongod

restarted server and started mongod but no change!

Comment: I could see anything different in your schema, or in your query, but I suspect `console.log()` can you remove the console log and give a try once for more than 100 records

Comment: What MongoDB server version you are running?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5

Comment: Looks like its fine with your query. Just to understand the issue, can your add some condition in your find query like  db.docs.find({"r1": 3}).limit(somenumber).toArray()

Comment: @ClementAmarnath the `console.log` was put in after to debug the problem. It shows that `find` does not complete and so `console.log` never fires. It is really odd that you think that.

Comment: @jerry `db.docs.find({"r1":{$gt:-1}).limit(200)...` hangs where as the same line with `limit(100)` is ok.

Comment: Can you tell me the length for the same query above whatever you checked - db.docs.find({"r1":{$gt:-1}).toArray().length

Comment: the length is undefined `console.log(db.collection('docs').find({"r1":{$gt:-1}).limit(200).toArray().length);`

Comment: Just tested on a different collection `find({}).limit(200)` is ok on a collection that only has a length fo 101 or less. as soon as it has to look through more results it hangs

Comment: Try using an index

Comment: Using an index `find({}).sort({_id:1}).limit(200)` still hangs

Comment: There has been similar questions in the past, but they were also using Mongoose in the stack. Still, try upgrading your version of the Node `mongodb` package and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by a Mongodb staff (Christian Amor Kvalheim) members advice to upgrade

```
npm install mongodb@2.2.4
```