# mongoDB query find is limited at 100?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

my application is no longer functional !

I found this without success : [mongodb db.collection.find({}) does nothing past .limit(101)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470345/mongodb-db-collection-find-does-nothing-past-limit101)

My application was stable during few months and I didn't update my scripts.

For few days, some queries don't work anymore !

**Here your are : my origin script but it doesn't work anymore :**

```
console.log("GO_1"); // display ok

models.myCollectionOne.find().sort({ created: 'desc' }).then(function (err,data) {
  console.log("GO_2"); // here I've got nothing on console
  console.log(err); // here I've got nothing on console
  console.log(data);  // here I've got nothing on console
}
// here nothing happens ?
```

**I tested this :**

```
models.myCollectionOne.find().limit(101).then(function (data) {
  console.log("GO_2"); // OK
  console.log(data); // ok
}
```

**So, my questions are :**

1) Why does my origin script doesn't work anymore ?

2) Do you know if there have been updates impacting my script?

3) Why limit(101) works and not limit(102 or more) ?

Thank for your help

Comment: What version of MongoDB do you use? The fix seems to have been introduced in MongoDB 2.2.4.

Comment: thank @Hampus MongoDB version : 3.2.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found my problem, I just need to update all my node module package, mainly mongoose,

So now, all works very well.

By the way, I have seen that I updated my main package.json but not the module npm itself ;-)

@Hampus @andrek thank for you help guys

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is on the `sort`. I think that 'desc' is not a valid value, you could try replacing it with -1: `{ created: -1 }`

(I've just tested using 'desc' here and got `"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification"`)

Perhaps you Mongodb got updated and it stopped working?

Comment: Hello, and thank @andrek , I remove sort and I have this script : "models.myCollectionOne.find().sort({ created: 'desc' }).then(function (err,data) {" but I have the same problem

Comment: @andrek My Mongodb is hosted on https://mlab.com/ so I can't not modify the version

Comment: @andrek the Mongodb works because with this query : "models.myCollectionOne.find().limit(101).then(function (data) {"

Comment: @DonFabiolas you removed the sort from the query and still getting the error? If you remove the limit from the query that works for you, does it stop working?

Comment: As for the Mongo version, if you use the free tier of mongolab, they made an upgrade to all 2.6 Mongolab versions to Mongo 3 on Sep 27. Could be related

Comment: @andrek
1) you removed the sort from the query and still getting the error? yes
2) If I remove the limit => it doesn't work
3) Yes, I think the mlab or mongo update from 27 Sep 2016 has impacted the normal functioning (a lot of our queries doesn't work anymore)